# Magento - 'proceed to checkout' button to go to login page if not logged in

Tags: magento, authentication, checkout

When a user who is not logged in (anonymous) clicks `Proceed to checkout`, I want them the be taken to the **login page**. Then, after they've logged in or registered, they should be taken back to the **checkout page**.

I'm using onepage checkout, which has a login section you're not logged in, but *the powers that be* don't want this.

Initially, I started down the route of changing `checkout.xml` to have these values:

```xml
<customer_logged_in>

    <block type="core/text_list" name="checkout.cart.top_methods" as="top_methods" translate="label">
        <label>Payment Methods Before Checkout Button</label>
        <block type="checkout/onepage_link" name="checkout.cart.methods.onepage" template="checkout/onepage/link.phtml"/>
    </block>

</customer_logged_in>

<customer_logged_out>

    <block type="core/text_list" name="checkout.cart.top_methods" as="top_methods" translate="label">
        <label>Payment Methods Before Checkout Button</label>
        <block type="checkout/onepage_link_not_logged_in" name="checkout.cart.methods.onepage" template="checkout/onepage/link_not_logged_in.phtml"/>
    </block>

</customer_logged_out>
```

And `link_not_logged_in.phtml`:

```php
$this->getLoginUrl();
```

but this did not even pull my new phtml file, and I'm not even sure this would take me to the checkout page after. Any articles or help greatly receieved.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Go to your site's `admin`.  Click `Stores`.  Go to `Configuration` -> `Sales` -> `Checkout` -> `Checkout Options` and set `Allow Guest Checkout` to "No"`

`edit`

Open `app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/onepage.phtml`.  Place the following code at the very top of the file:

```
   <?php
          if (!$this->helper('customer')->isLoggedIn()) {
                 header("Location: /customer/account/login/");
                 exit();
          }
   ?>
```

Finally, install `Custom Login Redirect` at https://marketplace.magento.com/magehit-magehit-customloginredirect.html.  Go to Admin -> System -> Configuration -> Customers -> Custom Login Redirect.  Set it to `checkout/cart`

All set!  I tested this and it does what you have described.  Normally I would go through all of the various steps to complete the revisions that are present in these Extensions but you can see that by going to app/code/local and viewing the extension code.

Comment: this is how it's currently set. We don't want the customer to sign in/ register with us on the onepage checkout screen we want them to do this on the login/create account page.

Comment: Hi Sean, i didn't need to install the addon, simply adding the php code:          <?php
          if (!$this->helper('customer')->isLoggedIn()) {
                 header("Location: /customer/account/login/");
                 exit();
          }
   ?>
to the onepage.phtml file did the trick.

Comment: I was also able to use this to hide and show the sign in / register buttons at my leisure.

Comment: @TejabhagavanKollepara Done.

Answer (score 0):

You have no block Mage/Checkout/Block/Onepage/Link/Not/Logged/In.php that you trying to access

If you creating this link directly in **checkout/onepage/link_not_logged_in.phtml** so you must use such code

```
<customer_logged_out>
    <block type="core/text_list" name="checkout.cart.top_methods" as="top_methods" translate="label">
        <label>Payment Methods Before Checkout Button</label>
        <block type="checkout/onepage_link" name="checkout.cart.methods.onepage" template="checkout/onepage/link_not_logged_in.phtml"/>
    </block>
</customer_logged_out>
```

So your block type must be the same for this as was in standart

Comment: Hi Kudja, apologies on the v delayed response. I'm not quite sure what you mean?

Answer (score 0):

The answer from seanbreeden pointed me in the right direction, but I think there is some extra info and some improvements that can be made.

You'll need to add a redirect from the checkout to the login page. An easy place to do this is in the checkout template. If you're using onepage checkout and default design, that would be `app/design/frontend/default/default/template/remove/checkout/onepage.phtml`. Just add this code to the top of that template (inside `<?php ?>` tags).

```php
if (!$this->helper('customer')->isLoggedIn()) {
    // Add a message that will display on the login page
    Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addError('Please log in or create an account to checkout.');

    // Create the redirection
    header("Location: " . $this->helper('customer')->getLoginUrl());
    exit();
}
```

Note the use of `getLoginUrl()`, this will allow Magento to redirect to the checkout page after the user logs in.

Comment: Hi, I have tested your code, but in my case Magento is redirecting back to cart instead of taking me to the checkout page. Anything wrong?